# What the best way for configuring DateTimeNormalizer in symfony 5

Tags: symfony

I have endpoint for getting info about current user:

```
/**
 * @Route("/users/me", name="me", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function me(): JsonResponse
{
    $classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));

    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory);

    $serializer = new Serializer([
        new DateTimeNormalizer([
            DateTimeNormalizer::FORMAT_KEY => 'Y-m-d'
        ]),
        $normalizer

    ], [new JsonEncoder()]);

    return JsonResponse::fromJsonString(
        $this->serializer->serialize($this->security->getUser(), 'json', [
            AbstractNormalizer::GROUPS => ['me'],

        ])
    );
}
```

but I also have multiple similar endpoints where I should get info about other entities (company, address etc) that have timestamp properties (created_at, updated_at etc) and as for me it is not a good approach to copypaste this code. How to configure DateTimeNormalizer(set FORMAT_KEY) in one place? Is it possible to do in services.yaml?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
// config/services.yaml
date_time_normalizer:
    class: Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\DateTimeNormalizer
    arguments: [{datetime_format: "Y-m-d H:i:s"}]
    tags: [serializer.normalizer]
```